# Programmatically disable all IE7 add-ons EXCEPT one

Tags: internet-explorer-7, add-on

Is there a way to do the following

1) disable all add-ons for an IE session (like the -extoff option)
2) then enable 1 (or some) add-ons only

I want to do this from a .cmd file

Other close but not quite options welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable / disable controls by twiddling some bits in the registry:

Go find this/these keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings\{CLSID}
```

...where {CLSID} is the id of the control you want to change.  It will have the following DWORD value in each key:

```
Flags
```

If the key exists and the least significant bit is set then the extension is disabled.

So, write a script to go do that using the REG command.